# Margins not being honored by IE

Tags: css

I have a form with a set of fieldsets.  These fieldsets will be conditionally hidden and shown server side so I need these fieldsets to flow left to right top to bottom.  The code below achieves this however the margin-bottom of 10px is not being honored by IE (IE7 only tested).

I read some posts that suggest this has to do with margins collapsing if you don;t add padding but I tried this and the same thing happens.  How can I create a 10px space between 2 lines of fieldsets?

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        fieldset {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 30%;
            height:90px;
            vertical-align: top;
            border: 1px solid black;
            margin-bottom:10px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <fieldset>
            <label>Label:</label>
            <input type="text"/>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <label>Label:</label>
            <input type="text"/>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <label>Label:</label>
            <input type="text"/>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <label>Label:</label>
            <input type="text"/>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <label>Label:</label>
            <input type="text"/>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For IE 6 and 7,

```
display: inline;
zoom: 1;
```

on a block-level element is equivalent to `inline-block` because `zoom` triggers IE's `hasLayout` property (read more about it [here](http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html))

Answer (score 1):

From: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html

> In IE 6 and 7 inline-block works only on elements that have a natural display: inline.
>
> Firefox 2 and lower don't support this value. You can use -moz-inline-box, but be aware that it's not the same as inline-block, and it may not work as you expect in some situations.

Fieldsets have a natural display:block, not inline, so IE6/7 is getting upset.

Try changing inline-block to just 'block' (or 'inline' if you want them on the same line) and see if that fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think IE likes to screw up inline-block - what if you just use block?  That should fix the problem.

Comment: Nope.  Doesn't wrap then.  Each element is on a new line.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the display from inline-block to inline then it works fine in IE7 and FF3.